# dynamic json file from mysql data arrays using php loops

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, loops

try create json data from mysql data base but im having problem in array loops.

mysql tables:

```
 table item 


         item_ id  item_name p_id
          1         item1     1
          2         item2     2


table product_info 

         p_ id  size      color
          1     medium    white
          2      large     red
```

here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_id, item_name FROM items";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);             
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {                   
    $item_id = $row[0];               
    $items[] = $row['item_name'];            
    $sql1 = "SELECT color, size FROM product_info where product_id = '$item_id'";  

    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);  

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1) { 
        $items[] = $row;
    }
}

 echo json_encode($items);
```

and output this:

```
[
 "item1",{"color":"white","size":"medium"},
 "item2",{"color":"red","size":"large"}
]
```

Im having a hard time assigning items => info.

supposedly my desired output will be like this:

```
{ 
  "item1":{"color":"white","size":"medium"},
  "item2":{"color":"red","size":"large"}
}
```

I tried concatenation on PHP script but its getting worse when encoded to json. 
need your corrections..

Comment: Please show `$items` value

Comment: I suggest to use join in SQL to get your result not two SQL statements

Comment: BTW: It is very unclear why you expect this result without knowing the data in the database

Comment: my apology. items row is this   $items[] = $row['item_name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change `$items[1] = $row[1];` to `$item_name = $row[1]` and `$items[] = $row;` to `$items[$item_name] = $row;`